# Hide Url while redirecting in iis or .htaccess and issues with digital certificate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, iis-6, reverse-proxy

I have a page that is **helpdesk.xxx.com** and I need to redirect it to an external url **https://xxx.dyndns.org:49551**
So far it work with this code

```
RewriteEngine on

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^helpdesk\.xxx\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/xxx\.dyndns\.org\:\49551" [L]
```

The problem is that I need that when the user goes to **helpdesk.xxx.com** the url don't keep the same after redirect .

i need that the url keep the same or at least that i can hide the ports

1. I tried with iframes but the there is a problem with the digital certificate and all the browser block the page
2. I tried with reverse proxy in the .htaccess file but I have no idea what I am doing
3. As is a external dns I can manage the config file of the php I only can work with the .htaccess in the php or with iis 6 in my own domain

Answer (score 0):

When the `https://xxx.dyndns.org:49551` is in a rewrite rule's target, it tells apache to redirect the browser to the new URL. That means the URL in the browser's address bar changes. You need to use a reverse proxy.

Ideally, you really want to be using directives like [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and `ProxyPassMatch`, because you can also pair them with `ProxyPassReverse` and the proxy pass cookie directives. The latter directives allows rewriting of the location fields, so when a request sent to `https://xxx.dyndns.org:49551` ends up returning as a redirect, the redirected location will be rewritten to `helpdesk.xxx.com` instead of the proxied one. Same with cookie domains and paths. However, these directives can only go in server or vhost configs, and not in an htaccess file. So if you don't have access to those, you'll need to rely on mod_rewrite.

So mod_rewrite has a `P` flag that you can use. It tells the rewrite engine to pass the reverse proxy request off to mod_proxy. This should work fine but you're not going to get any of the location rewriting or the cookie rewriting the mod_proxy has. So you just need to change your rule to include a `P` in the square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/xxx\.dyndns\.org\:\49551" [L,P]
```

This won't work unless you have the mod_proxy module loaded.